# Amazon Lex authorization with Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-lex

I want write Flutter app which work with Amazon Lex REST API.Amazon has specific way for [authenticating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) I used [SigV4](https://pub.dev/packages/sigv4) package to make required headers

```
  Sigv4Client client = Sigv4Client(
  keyId: kAccessKey,
  accessKey: kSecretKey,
  region: "us-east-1",
  serviceName: "lex",
);

final request = client.request(
  "https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bot/myBotName/alias/BETA/user/myUserId/text",
  method: 'POST',
  body: jsonEncode({'inputText': 'hi'}),
);

var response=post(request.url, headers: request.headers, body: request.body);
print(response.body);
```

but i get this message in print :

```
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
```

I get valid response on postman with same data the only part is different in postman and this package is "X-Amz-Content-Sha256" value and of course Signature value (it change every time) .
"X-Amz-Content-Sha256" postman value:

```
beaead3198f7da1e70d03ab969765e0821b24fc913697e929e726aeaebf0eba3
```

"X-Amz-Content-Sha256" my code value:

```
ee9ef87bd5a357cff93b1d83d1e8a1b47fb3fa2e94251711c6a30250119e6369
```

I tried to write function to calculate authenticating string but it was so complex for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the package and use [amazon-cognito-identity-dart-2](https://github.com/furaiev/amazon-cognito-identity-dart-2)

and send the request like this :

```
AwsSigV4Client client=AwsSigV4Client(
      kAccessKey,
      kSecretKey,
      'https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      serviceName: 'lex',
    );

final signedRequest = new SigV4Request(
      client,
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/bot/MyBotName/alias/BETA/user/MyUser/text',
      headers: new Map<String, String>.from({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'ACCEPT': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: new Map<String, dynamic>.from({"inputText": "hi"}),
    );

var response = await http.post(
      signedRequest.url,
      headers: signedRequest.headers,
      body: signedRequest.body,
    );
```

it so important to add

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

in your headers .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I set `defaultContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` in AwsSigV4Client and removed the `headers` from SigV4Request:

```
AwsSigV4Client client=AwsSigV4Client(
  accessKey,
  secretKey,
  'https://runtime.lex.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  region: 'eu-west-2',
  serviceName: 'lex',
  defaultContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
);

final signedRequest = new SigV4Request(
  client,
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/bot/MyBotName/alias/BETA/user/MyUser/text',
  body: new Map<String, dynamic>.from({"inputText": "hi"}),
);
```